# Equations of motion on sphere with drag term

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, coordinate-systems, drag

I am trying to figure out how to supplement the equations of motion of a free particle on a sphere

$$\displaystyle
\ddot{\theta} = \dot{\phi}^2 \sin \theta \cos \theta    \\
\displaystyle
\ddot{\phi} = - 2 \dot{\phi} \dot{\theta} \frac{1}{\tan \theta}$$

with a drag term

$$ \dot{\mathbf{v}} = -\gamma \mathbf{v}$$

It seems pretty clear to me that the equation for $\ddot{\theta}$ will be supplemented like so

$$ \ddot{\theta} = \dot{\phi}^2 \sin \theta \cos \theta -\gamma \dot{\theta} $$

But I am getting really confused about what happens with $\ddot{\phi}$. 
As I've worked it out, I get

$$ \displaystyle \ddot{\phi} = - 2 \dot{\phi} \dot{\theta} \frac{1}{\tan \theta}  - \gamma \dot{\phi} $$

But intuitively, it seems to me that $\sin\theta$ ought to be accounted for in that term somehow. 
Does anyone know the correct way to do this?

Comment: The position vector of a sphere is $\overrightarrow{R}=\overrightarrow{R}\left( \theta ,\phi \right) $ and the velocity $\overrightarrow{v}=\dfrac{\partial \overrightarrow{R}}{\partial \theta }\dfrac{d\theta }{dt}+\dfrac{\partial \overrightarrow{R}}{\partial \phi }\dfrac{d\phi }{dt}$ so the Drag Force is $F= \left( \dfrac{\partial \overrightarrow{R}}{\partial \overrightarrow{q}}\right) ^{T}\left( -\gamma \overrightarrow{v}\right) $

Comment: Hi bob.sacamento. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework-and-exercises](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework-and-exercises/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: from http://mathworld.wolfram.com]

> http://mathworld.wolfram.com

the  particle  position vector $\vec{R}$ is :

$$\vec{R}=r\,\left[ \begin {array}{c} \cos \left( \theta \right) \sin \left( \phi
 \right) \\ \sin \left( \theta \right) \sin \left( 
\phi \right) \\ \cos \left( \phi \right) 
\end {array} \right]  
\tag 1$$

from equation (1) you can obtain the kinetic $T$ and potential energy $U$

$$T=\frac{m}{2}\vec{\dot{R}}\cdot\vec{\dot{R}}=$$ 
and 
$$U=m\,g\,\vec{R}_z$$

the drag force is :

$$\vec{F}_D=-d\,\vec{\dot{R}}$$

if you calculate  the equations of motion with Euler Lagrange method, the drag force is a generalized external force $\vec{F}_Q$ on the RHS of the E.L equations

$$\vec{F}_Q=\left(\frac{\partial \vec{R}}{\partial \vec{q}}\right)^T\,\vec{F}_D  $$

where $\vec{q}=[\theta,\phi]^T$

$$\vec{F}_Q=  d\,r^2\begin{bmatrix}
   \sin^2(\phi)\,\dot{\theta} \\
   \dot{\phi} \\
 \end{bmatrix}
$$
thus 
the equations of motion are:

$$\ddot{\theta}+2\,{\frac {\cos \left( \phi \right) {\it \dot{\theta}}\,{\it \dot{\phi}}}{\sin
 \left( \phi \right) }}+{\frac {{\it \dot{\theta}}\,d}{m}}=0
$$

$${\it \ddot{\phi}}+{\frac {{\it \dot{\phi}}\,d}{m}}-{{\it \dot{\theta}}}^{2}\cos \left( 
\phi \right) \sin \left( \phi \right) -{\frac {g\sin \left( \phi
 \right) }{r}}
=0$$

Comment: Thanks!  I take it that in the $\ddot{\phi}$ equation, you mean $\sin(\theta)$?

Comment: @bob.sacamento this is because i use different position vector $\vec{R}$ then you did?

Comment: Ah!  I see!  I think in terms of $\phi$ being azimuthal, and you think in terms of $\phi$ being zonal.  A common misunderstanding, I have found!  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

This can be solved most elegantly (but may be less intuitively)
by the Lagrangian method with dissipation.
See [Lagrangian mechanics - Extensions to include non-conservative forces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_mechanics#Extensions_to_include_non-conservative_forces).

The Lagrangian function of your free particle (mass $m$)
on a sphere (constant radius $R$) is
$$L = \frac{m}{2}\mathbf{v}^2
 = \frac{m}{2}R^2(\dot{\theta}^2+\sin^2\theta\ \dot{\phi}^2)
$$

The [Rayleigh dissipation function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_dissipation_function) $D$ is
chosen so that it generates the drag force
$\mathbf{F}_d=-\frac{\partial D}{\partial\mathbf{v}}
=-\gamma\mathbf{v}$.
That is
$$D = \frac{\gamma}{2}\mathbf{v}^2
  = \frac{\gamma}{2}R^2(\dot{\theta}^2+\sin^2\theta\ \dot{\phi}^2)
$$

The Lagrangian equations (including dissipation) for $\theta$ and $\phi$ are
$$ \frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{\theta}}\right)
 -\frac{\partial L}{\partial \theta}
 + \frac{\partial D}{\partial\dot{\theta}} = 0
$$
$$ \frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{\phi}}\right)
 - \frac{\partial L}{\partial\phi}
 + \frac{\partial D}{\partial\dot{\phi}} = 0
$$

Doing the calculus is straight-forward, and you get
the equations of motion
$$\ddot{\theta}=\sin\theta\cos\theta\ \dot{\phi}^2
 - \frac{\gamma}{m}\dot{\theta}$$
$$\ddot{\phi}=-\frac{2}{\tan\theta}\dot{\theta}\dot{\phi}
 - \frac{\gamma}{m}\dot{\phi}$$